# Получение json от другого сервера в angular

Tags: json, angularjs, http

```
$scope.result = "";
$http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/user_signin',
          data: { username: $scope.user.username, password: $scope.user.password },
          responseType:'json'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
             console.log('success');
             $scope.result = response;
             console.log($scope.result);
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
             console.log('error');
             console.log(response);
          });
```

Результат в консоли:

```
Object {data: null, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

Что я делаю не так? Почему `data:null`? В postman сервер возвращает это: `{"response_code":200,"salt":"76d2772eaf0a1ef2bed8fc423ca98af87c664b5b"}`

Мне нужен доступ к переменной `salt`.

Network: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43901/discussion-on-question-by-j-doe--json-----angular).